# Colab Notebooks stored in Github are not readable in code preview mode

Tags: github, google-colaboratory

I use Google Colab in my class and I share the notebooks / data with my students by storing them in a public repository in Github. Colab allows this and also places a 'open with colab' button at the top which is very convenient.

When anyone browses the repository they can easily preview the contents of the Colab Notebook and depending on whether they want to use it, they can click on the blue button.

Of late, I notice that recently saved notebooks cannot be previewed in Github. I have to first go to colab.research.google.com and then open the notebook by inserting the notebook's URL. Obviously this rather cumbersome and inconvenient. However some of my old notebooks are can still be previewed.

I have tried with Edge, Brave and Chrome with the same result.

I also notice that github has a beta version of the interface. Is this the problem? Can I go back to the old status? What is the way forward on this. Will be grateful for any advice.

EDIT : I note that the problem seems to be erratic. Some repositories, note notebooks are perfectly viewable. Others are not